# How to deploy an i18n Angular with Azure Static web app

Tags: angular, internationalization, azure-static-web-app

I am working on a Angular 14 application. This application is localized @angular/localize.
When I run the npm build, I added --localize. The folder structure created by the build is:
***dist -> app-name -> local (fr, en, de..)***

I push the dist folder in a very simple Nodejs. It is working like a charm.

Now I want to deploy the application on Azure Static web app. I go to the portal, and I create the application.
And now the build failed:
***Failed to find a default file in the app artifacts folder (dist/app_name). Valid default files: index.html,Index.html***

I undedstand the reason. If I push a non i18n application, the deployment is Ok, as the build create only one index.html in dist/app_name.
I tried:

- to use assets in the in angular.json to copy an index.html directly under /dist/app_name. But angular copy always in the local directory.
- I run a post build event: ng build --configuration production --localize && cp /postbuild/index.html dist. This command works perfectly on my local env. However, on azure the error comes directly after the ng build, meaning before the cp command.
- I deployed an staticwebapp.config.json. But the redirect is when the application is deployed, not during compilation time.

When I use the command: ***ng build --configuration production --localize=en*** , angular deploy only the en localization. Therefore everything runs.

So **my question is: is it possible to run an i18n angular on azure static web app without creating one static webapp for each locale?**
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need your `staticwebapp.config.json` with the necessary redirects of your locales, you will have to decide which one is the default. I don't know if there is a way to configure the accept-language header for the routes.

```
{
    "routes": [
        {
            "route": "*.{js,json,css,jpg,png,ico,webmanifest}"
        },
        {
            "route": "/index.html",
            "rewrite": "/es-CL/index.html"
        },
        {
            "route": "/en-US/*",
            "rewrite": "/en-US/index.html"
        },
        {
            "route": "/it-IT/*",
            "rewrite": "/it-IT/index.html"
        },
        {
            "route": "/es-CL/*",
            "rewrite": "/es-CL/index.html"
        }
    ]
}
```

then you need to create an empty Index.html file in the root of the app (dist/index.html)

I do this by adding an Agent Job in your pipeline just before publishing the SPA:

```
steps:
- script: |
   echo "<html></html>" > index.html
   ls
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Your app dist'
  displayName: 'Command Line Script'
```

Comment: each of my index.html files have the appropriate <base href="/en" /> ..etc  but all my assets don't seem to be loading from those base locations. (thus yielding a "Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.")

Comment: Update: that turned out to be a build issue. baseHref for each locale needed to be set.  What's interesting now, however, is https://<domain>/en/ works ... but https://<domain>/en/profile does not work properly.  need to figure out how to update the swa config to fix that

Comment: @Kirby would you please elaborate your solution?

Answer (score -1):

Hey I was going to make a video but contact me I can help you out
if you dont have time follow this doc I made

go to manage deployment token in static web apps in azure portal

also for localization you don't want to use angular localization, I much rather use '@ngx-translate'

- you want to run the deploy command from the directory root

  - --env flag deploy to production

```
npx swa deploy ./dist/azureSWA  --deployment-token [Your deployment token] --env production
```

Comment: You can also do:  in your pacakge.json   "build:azure:qual": "ng build --configuration qual --localize && touch dist/mmc-workspace/index.html". The touch command solved my issue. But you have to maintain a staticwebapp.config.json